# How to select best N list from a pool of M lists having to get the maximum number of unique elements?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming, permutation

For example, I have 7 lists as shown below. These lists can be of length **l>0**.
`

```
L1 = [1,2,3,4]  
L2 = [1,2,3,4,5]  
L3 = [6,7]  
L4 = [1,6,8,9]  
L5 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,10]  
L6 = [1,2,3,4]  
L7 = [10,11,12,13]
```

I want to select the best combination of 4 lists from this pool of above-mentioned 7 lists (L1, L2,...,L7) to get the highest number of unique elements.

**Output**: L2, L3, L4, L7   --> Since, it has 13 unique values.

Any ideas on how to proceed?
Also, any smart way to solve this?

Comment: Are you familiar with Python `set` operations? You could try it first. If you still get stuck - then please post your code/question, people will be able to help you then.

Comment: What are the constraints on the number of lists and the length on each list?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur, let's consider that we 10,000 Lista, and each list can be of max 20 elements. I have posted a solution. Do you have any other approach?

Comment: @Priyanka is there any constraint on the range of values in the list?

Answer (score 0):

@DanielHao, Thank you for giving me the hint! I tried to implement and the solution is as below. However, I am not sure if this the optimized way or not.

`

```
# Choosing combinations of 4 Lists from existing 7.
# Calculating union of those 4 chosen set to calculate unique elements.
# Save the highest length.

from itertools import combinations  

comb = combinations([L1, L2, L3, L4, L5, L6, L7], 4)  
temp_best_score = 0
temp_best_comb = None

for i in list(comb):
   temp_val = set()
   for j in range(len(i)):
     temp_val = temp_val|set(i[j])
   current_score = len(temp_val)
   if(current_score > temp_best_score):
     temp_best_score = current_score
     temp_best_comb = i

best_score = temp_best_score
best_comb = temp_best_comb
```

`

- Output:

**best_comb:**
([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7], [1, 6, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13])
**best_score:**
13

Comment: Good Job. You're very close - made great progress by learning this `set()` operations.  But it seems there are still some syntax errors: eg. this line should be:   for j in range(len(i)):
        tmp_val = `tmp_val | set(i[j])`

Comment: @DanielHao Thank you very for the input! It makes no sense to convert all the List to Set which I did initially. I am editing that as you suggested.